# BeanPostprocessor is not invoked for beans, that are autowired as list of map

Tags: spring

I faced with very strange (unexpected) behaviour with `BeanPostProcessors`, let's suppose we got the following configuration:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestConfiguration.class);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public String bean1() {
            return "1";
        }

        @Bean
        public String bean2() {
            return "2";
        }

        @Bean
        public Integer bean3() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Bean
        public BeanPostProcessor postProcessor() {
            return new BeanPostProcessor() {
                @Override
                public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                    return bean;
                }

                @Override
                public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                    System.out.println(beanName);
                    return bean;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

So, when we run this code, it'll print names of all beans:

- bean1
- bean2
- bean3

Using specified post-processor.

But when I'm using an `@Autowire` annotation, to have all beans of type `String`, beans of this type are not `post-processed` by existing post-processor, which seems very strange to me.

Example of such configuration is the following:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestConfiguration.class);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfiguration {

        @Autowired(required = false)
        private List<String> stringBeans = new ArrayList<>();

        @Bean
        public String bean1() {
            return "1";
        }

        @Bean
        public String bean2() {
            return "2";
        }

        @Bean
        public Integer bean3() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Bean
        public BeanPostProcessor postProcessor() {
            return new BeanPostProcessor() {
                @Override
                public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                    return bean;
                }

                @Override
                public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                    System.out.println(beanName);
                    return bean;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The version of spring core is **4.3.8.RELEASE**

Thx !

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the logs more carefully, you will see these lines

> [main] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -
>   Eagerly caching bean 'bean1' to allow for resolving potential circular
>   references
>
> [main] INFO 
>    org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker
>   - Bean 'bean1' of type [java.lang.String] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for
>   auto-proxying)

This is for bean1, you will have similar logs for bean2 as well. As the message says, bean1 is not eligible for Autoproxying.

This is kinda chicken and egg problem. Since you have your BeanPostProcessor code inside the same class, it is not able to create the bean completely and hence `postProcessAfterInitialization` is not getting called.

[Here](https://synyx.de/blog/bean-x-of-type-y-is-not-eligible-for-getting-processed-by-all-beanpostprocessors/) is a nice article with more information on this.

A simple fix for this would be to move your `BeanPostProcessor` code to a separate class.

Comment: Hi, I'm very grateful for your reply, thx a lot, I'll check )